# bolt heads with bevel modifiers causing tons of artifacts

Tags: modeling, workflow, bevel

So the geometry on the bolts that come in the 'bolt factory' plug in are not ideal for making a high poly bolt with bevels and a subd. At least for the phillips head.

Curious to how some of you model high poly bolt heads for hard surface game assets?

Comment: could you please show some pictures of what you have / what you want?

Comment: Why would you want a *"high poly bolt heads for hard surface game assets"*? Shouldn't that be a low-poly object for a game?  - You could duplicate, then remesh the new object and sculpt in the imperfections, and finally bake a normal map for the low-poly version.